# Check if another Report exists before launching it

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

The Map polygon Action can launch another Report.

Is there a way to check that a particular report actually exists before blindly trying to launch it?

This would allow re-direction to an 'Oops!' dummy report instead of it erroring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the `ReportServer` database directly (It is called `ReportServer` by default, though this can be different).

All of your SSRS items - from reports to subscriptions - are held in here somewhere.  If you want to check for a report, you can search the `Catalog` table on both `Path` and `Name`.

If you can build a dataset of the reports you want to link to, you can then replace the ones that have no match in `Catalog` with a link to your `Oops!` report.

Comment: It doesn't sound like I can do that in the Expression used to define the name of the Report to jump to...

Comment: @radders  No, you wouldn't.  You would need to either include the check in your original dataset or create a new dataset and do a `lookup` in your `Action` expression.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That would work. (Note: I am Dave too!!)